# R: How add characters in a string based on other string marker positions?

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I want to add markers in a string based on marker positions from another string. I have the SOURCE data frame with two columns: "ortho" and "syllabify". I want to create the TARGET column using the "underline" markers. Strings from "ortho" should be separated by "underlines" accordingly to "underlines" position in "sillabify".

> df <- data.frame("agradece", "R_OOR_OR_OR")

```
SOURCE:  
   ortho    syllabify       
agradeço  R_OOR_OR_OR  
    bala        OR_OR        
 futebol    OR_OR_ORC    

TARGET:  
   ortho    syllabify       TARGET
agradeço  R_OOR_OR_OR  a_gra_de_ço    
    bala        OR_OR        ba_la
 futebol    OR_OR_ORC    fu_te_bol
```

Thank you all!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used gregexpr(x@syllabify) to get the string positions of the "underline" marker. Now, how to use these positions to insert "underline" markers in the appropriate positions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you think in (Gustavo, Melisso), but this, in Java is the answer:

Initializers:

```
String sillabify = "OR_OR_ORC";
String ortho = "futebol";
String answer = returnTheTARGETColumnStringUsingTheUnderlineMarkers(ortho, sillabify);
```

Method:

```
public String returnTheTARGETColumnStringUsingTheUnderlineMarkers(String pOrtho, String pSillabify) {
    String target = "";

    int ind = 0;
    while (pSillabify.contains("_")) {
        target = target + pOrtho.substring(0, pSillabify.indexOf("_")) + "_";
        pOrtho = pOrtho.substring(pSillabify.indexOf("_"), pOrtho.length());
        pSillabify = pSillabify.substring(pSillabify.indexOf("_") + 1, pSillabify.length());
    }

    target = target + pOrtho;

    return target;
}
```

Returns "fu_te_bol".

Comment: Tks, that looks to the job. Nevertheless, I am using R Cran program. This function should be applied for 33M words, thus, I am looking for something less machine consuming. Looking for a solution using R functions and regex optimaly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   ortho    syllabify       
agradeço  R_OOR_OR_OR  
    bala        OR_OR        
 futebol    OR_OR_ORC", header = TRUE)

library(purrr)
df <- within(df, {
  ortho <- as.character(ortho)

  underscore_loc <- gregexpr("_", syllabify)
  target <- map2(ortho, underscore_loc, function(string, loc) {
    locs <- cbind(c(1, loc) - pmax(0, 1 + 0:length(loc) - 2), c(loc, nchar(string)) - c(1:length(loc), 0))
    strings <- apply(locs, 1, function(x) substr(string, x[1], x[2]))
    paste(strings, collapse = "_")
  })
  rm(underscore_loc)
})
df
#>      ortho   syllabify      target
#> 1 agradeço R_OOR_OR_OR a_gra_de_ço
#> 2     bala       OR_OR       ba_la
#> 3  futebol   OR_OR_ORC   fu_te_bol
```

Created on 2018-06-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

The `purrr` package is used to get the `map2` function - which is like `lapply`, but works input across 2 lists.